# jq - apply a filter on multiple levels

Tags: json, recursion, jq, flatten

I have a json file like this

```
{
    "log": {
            "version": {
                    "$t": "1.1"
            },
            "creator": {
                    "name": {
                            "$t": "Internet Explorer Network Inspector"
                    },
                    "version": {
                            "$t": "10.0.9200.17229"
                    }
            }
}
```

And I need to flatten the file so it should read

```
{
    "log": {
            "version": "1.1",
            "creator": {
                    "name": "Internet Explorer Network Inspector",
                    "version": "10.0.9200.17229"
            }
}
```

I know the filter `{"version": .version ."$t"}` reduce the single element `"version": {"$t": "10.0.9200.17229"}` to `{"version": "10.0.9200.17229"}` but this filter should be applied recursively to any element at any level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a recursive filter by defining a new function:

```
def untag: (objects | ."$t")
    // (objects | with_entries(.value |= untag))
    // (arrays | map(untag))
    // .
    ;
untag
```

So given input like this:

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": {
      "$t": "1.1"
    },
    "creator": {
      "name": {
        "$t": "Internet Explorer Network Inspector"
      },
      "version": {
        "$t": "10.0.9200.17229"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get back:

```
{
  "log": {
    "creator": {
      "name": "Internet Explorer Network Inspector",
      "version": "10.0.9200.17229"
    },
    "version": "1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: So to explain.
We define a function `untag` that select inputs that are objects and if they have `$t` extract the value *otherwise*  update the value of the object with the value from `untag` (this is the recursive part). Finally if we don't have any `$t` the function return the input itself.

Comment: I've added a bit more to it to handle arrays if you have them. And the initial check for the `$t` property is not needed. I thought it was going to throw an error but it won't.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I was editing the answer to add the array handling. Hopefully I noticed the red alert on the top bar of stackoverflow ;-)

The rational of this is to transform the `NetworkData.xml` from IE in HAR format. The first XML > JSON tool I found [xml2json](https://github.com/parmentf/xml2json) is quite verbose so I need to flatten the result. Indeed there is another step, converting the object in `page`and `entries` to a plain array but this should be straightforward...

Comment: Where does one put the `untag` function and how is it invoked from the command line? I'm trying to something like this `some_command  | xml2json | jq` with `untag` applied.

Comment: @jwfearn you're just defining a new function so you would just insert it before it's needed. Or, you could put it in your `.jq` file in your home for rent in, then it would be available everywhere

Comment: @JeffMercado, I added `untag` to `~/.jq`. Do you know what arguments I use in place of `...` in the following command to apply the untag filter? `some_command | xml2json | jq ...`

Comment: @jwfearn just call it. `... | jq 'untag'`

Answer (score 0):

If your jq has `walk`, you could use it as follows, and if not, you can easily google its def and include it by cut-and-paste:

```
walk( if type=="object" and has("$t")
      then .["$t"] else . end )
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @JeffMercado's excellent answer:

**PROBLEM**

You have some command that produces JSON where string values represented like this

```
{"some key": {"$t": "some string value"}}
```

and you'd like to transform it to look like this:

```
{"some key": "some string value"}
```

**SOLUTION**

Put this in your `~/.jq` file:

```
def untag: (objects | ."$t")
  // (objects | with_entries(.value |= untag))
  // (arrays | map(untag))
  // .
  ;
```

Use it like this:

```
some_command | jq untag
```

Examples:

```
$ echo '{"some key": {"$t": "some string value"}}' | jq
{
  "some key": {
    "$t": "some string value"
  }
}

$ echo '{"some key": {"$t": "some string value"}}' | jq untag
{
  "some key": "some string value"
}
```